# How to efficiently get frequency of subranges and update its values altogether?

Tags: data-structures

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

There are `N` notes in an array (2<=N<=10<sup>5</sup>) labeled 0..N-1, all of them initially set to `1`. Then there follows `Q` operations to perform in the array (1<=Q<=10<sup>5</sup>).

The task for each operation is:

- Find the most frequent value between the inclusive range `[A,B]`.
- Add that value to all elements in the same range. The new values must be in range [0..8], then we take it modulo `9`.

At the end, output all array values.

---

This is the first problem of *"Maratona de Programação da SBC – ACM ICPC – 2017"* here in Brazil, and I'm trying to solve it in the [URI Online Judge site](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2658). Time Limit: 1 second.

---

First I tried SQRT Decomposition because it looked good, but it's not. This week I came up with a few nice ideas to solve it using Segment Tree. I was so sure my code was perfect... but it wans't. Time limit exceeded again.

I don't have Advanced Data Structures classes, I learn those things by myself. So I'm probably lacking some fancy tree structure that would solve this problem really faster. Please, give me some resource to learn such a structure.

---

Here is an [Ideone link](https://ideone.com/GwxGyZ) to my code. Let me describe the few nice ideas using Segment tree that I mentioned above:

- Storing the difference (delta) instead of values. With that I was able to update the ranges without going to the leaf nodes. And to find value of some node, ex: leaf node `[0,0]` for N=8, I can traverse from root to that node and sum up delta values `[0,7].delta + [0,3].delta + [0,1].delta + [0,0].delta`.
- Store in each node the count of every value [0..8] in its descendants and itself. Because each node represents a subrange, then the frequencies can be precalculated.
- Instead of recalculating the subrange array of frequencies, I can rotate it. Ex: If the most frequent note is `3`, the previous quantity of values 2 is now the quantity of values 5, and so on... so rotating makes sense instead of calculating the quantities of descendant nodes again.
- This is the most brilliant, *I think*. Instead of rotating, use the value (calculated using delta since root path) to find which index of the frequency subrange array should be treated as the first index 0.

I spent more than twenty hours over this week since the first version of the segment tree approach. It was not easy to think all the ideas I listed above. I know I'm not the best at it. But I think you can feel how frustrated I am, after getting Time Limit Exceeded in all of my attempts.

I also think I evolved since the Square Root Decomposition approach. The problem is that I am out of ideas to improve it further. If I didn't see that [156 people](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/ranks/problem/2658/cpp) have already solved it. I would think it is impossible.

Please, share a bit of your knowledge with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Our usual policy is not to interfere with ongoing programming competitions.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus. It was on September 9. Maybe the finals is not over yet. But ok then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost one year later... I tried to solve it today without looking my previous code and I got ACC'ed now. [(ideone link)](https://ideone.com/moZuCp)

Reading my question now, I've implemented what I called `delta` and `rotate` in a simpler way. I will try to illustrate.

This is how the segment tree for *N = 5* looks like after `build()`:

[image]

My node struct has:

```
int freq[9], i, lazy;
```

The `i` variable is the position circled in red in the picture, it will hold which position of the `freq` array contains the frequency for note `0` (which initially is zero). The `lazy` flag stores pending sums for children (both left and right), blue in the picture.

Now suppose first query for `[1, 2]`. The `query()` function will find nodes `[1, 1]` and `[2, 2]` and the resulting `int fquery[9]` array will have values `[0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. The `greatest()` value then is `1`. Ok, this is a simple search.

Now the function `chord()` will update those ranges by setting `lazy += 1` and `i -= 1`:

[image]

Note that since those are leaf nodes, the `lazy` property does nothing. Also note that since `i` was decreased, there is no need to update `freq[]` array. This two things were done in the pre-order traversal of the recursive `chord()` function.

Now we update the `freq[]` array of the parents using the post-order traversal of the recursive `chord()` function by calling `update()`, this update function is just a merge of left and right child nodes:

[image]

These separation of pre-order and post-order traversal of the recursive call was the main point that I didn't understand last year. I was trying to update the parents out of the recursion track, and it caused me TLE.

Now suppose second query for `[0, 4]`. The `query()` function will find node `[0, 4]` and the resulting `int fquery[9]` array will have values `[0,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. The `greatest()` value then is `1`.

Now the function `chord()` will set `lazy += 1` and `i -= 1`:

[image]

Since we found the desired range in the root, this time we don't have post-order traversal.

Now suppose third query for `[0, 2]`. The `query()` function will find node `[0, 2]`. *But*, we can only reach a node if there is no pending sums. So, we need to resolve the `lazy = 1` flag of node `[0, 4]`. This is what `propagate()` function does:

[image]

Note: the `i` value of node `[0, 2]` is `8`.

And the resulting `int fquery[9]` array will have values `[0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0]`. The `greatest()` value then is `3`.

Now the function `chord()` will set `lazy += 3` and `i -= 3`:

[image]

As previously, we update the `freq[]` array of the parents using the post-order `update()`:

[image]

To get the output after all queries, you just need to `propagate()` every node, doing so the leaf nodes will have the final values. You can check the `show()` function.

The output for this example will be: `5 6 6 2 2`. (The first test case in the URI Online Judge).

---

Conclusion: The solution to the problem is a standard segment tree with lazy propagation with each node containing an `int freq[9]` array and an additional index starter holder.

Comment: Can you summarize the main ideas behind your new approach?  Can you summarize the new simpler method for delta and rotate?  Just telling us that you have a new better way isn't as useful as telling us what the new useful way is.

Comment: @D.W. Edited, pardon my paint skills =) ... And feel free to fix any English mistakes.